# Intersections of compact sests.

Tags: general-topology

I am working on the following problem.

Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and let $\{C_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z_+}}$ be a collection of nonempty compact closed sets in $X$ satisfying $C_{i+1} \subset C_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z_+}$.  Prove $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}C_i \neq \varnothing$.

This is a homework problem ... so I would just like to see if I am going the the correct direction.

We must choose a open Cover say $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ where the $U_{\alpha}$'s are open in $X$.  Then we know that the cover is of the form $U_{\alpha} \cap \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}C_i$ and out of that we must construct a finite subcover that maybe will do something for us?  But I seem to be unable to get past that point...

Or maybe we should use contradiction?

Thank you

Comment: @Riemann-bitcoin, it is enough to assume one of them is compact. The rest (with higher numbers) are now compact as closed subsets of compact sets.

Comment: @szw1710 I agree

Comment: Consider the family $V_i = X \setminus C_i$. If the intersection were empty, it would be an open cover of $C_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a collection $\{C_i\}$ such that each $C_i$ is compact and nonempty and $C_{i+1}\subset C_i$. Assume that $\bigcap C_i=\emptyset$.

Now define $U_i=X\backslash C_i$. Note that each $U_i$ is open and $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$. Furthermore since $\bigcap C_i=\emptyset$ then $\bigcup U_i=X$. In particular $\{U_i\}$ is a covering of $C_0$. Since $C_0$ is compact, then there exists a finite subfamily of $\{U_i\}$ covering $C_0$. Furthermore since $U_i\subset U_j$ for $i<j$ then there's exactly one $U_j$ (the biggest index) covering entire $C_0$, so $C_0\subset U_j=X\backslash C_j$. That's a contradiction since $C_j\subset C_0$ and $C_j$ is nonempty.

Comment: but what part of this uses that $X$ is hausdorff

Comment: @Riemann-bitcoin. None. That assumption is not necessary.

Comment: ok I see @freakish